# Reset variable using shell

Tags: shell, ash

I use the shell script to reset variable.

```
 #!/bin/sh 
reset_var() { 
while [ "$#" -gt "0" ] do  
 echo "\$1 is $1"   
unset $1 done 
} 

i=50  
j= 40 
reset_var i j
```

but this it does not work!

the purpose is to reset i and j variable to 0

is there any way to reset many variables !

Comment: Insert a newline or semi-colon between `1` and `done` in the line `unset $1 done`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your situation, you do not need a `reset_var` function, simply do:

```
i=50
j=40
unset i j
```

That is said, a possible `reset_var` function would be:

```
reset_var() {
  while [ "${#}" -ge 1 ] ; do 
   unset "${1}"
   shift
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop when passing some arguments. Your reset function should look something like this:

```
reset_var() {
for arg
do
  unset ${arg}
done
}
```